# How do I resolve Epson Stylus SX415 communication issues on 18.04.1 LTS?

Tags: usb, printing, epson, cups-lpd

Printer seen. Print queue seen. Stays in processing mode with no output.
The Epson Printer is a Stylus SX415 (410).

But `cupsenable` doesn't resolve.
Any solutions?